# Trivial lemma not proving

Tags: assert, verification, proof, algebraic-data-types, dafny

I defined the following `datatype`, `function` and `lemma` for σ-algebra in Dafny. It seems to me that the lemma should prove but I get an assertion violation at the last assert statement.

```
datatype Alg = Empty | Complement(a: Alg) | Union(b: Alg, c: Alg)

const S : set<int>

function eval(X: Alg) : set<int>
    decreases X;
{
    match X
    case Empty => {}
    case Complement(a) => S - eval(X.a)
    case Union(b,c) => eval(X.b) + eval(X.c)
}

lemma algebra()
    ensures forall x :: exists y :: eval(y) == S - eval(x);
{
    var l : Alg;
    var c :| c == Complement(l);
    assert eval(c) == S - eval(l);
    assert exists a {:induction false} :: eval(a) == S - eval(l);
    assert forall x :: exists y :: eval(y) == S - eval(x);   // this statement does not prove
}
```

My proof follows this logic: Let `l` be an arbitrary `Alg` (σ-algebra) and let `c` be the complement of `l`. So for `l` there exists a `c` that is evaluated to S - the evaluation of `l`. Since `l` was an arbitrary `Alg`, shouldn't this generalize for all `Alg`'s?

Note, I also tried writing out the last assert statement as follows, but still got the violation.

```
assert forall x {:induction false} :: exists y {:induction false} :: eval(y) == S - eval(x);
```

Any idea why this is not proving or have a suggestion I could try?